# error 0x80070570 on installation of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation

Recently my friend tried to install Mac OS Mountain lion and Lion on my PC and everything was fine, but I decided to go back and use Windows on my PC since I have Macbook Pro already, but the problem occur that when I'm trying to install Windows 8 on my PC it just keep give me error `0x80070570` when I did a research (Google) found that many people report could be that some device that attach cause the error.

I don't have any thing that attach to my PC at the moment, so that couldn't be a problem.

I found a topic posted here in superuser.com said that it can be fix but cancel it before when the error occur and re-do the installation again and should be fix, but that doesn't help.

I'm not sure if it is because of my hard drive is not format in the right way, so I'm trying to format it to the Windows format (NTFS) or (FAT32) but I don't know how to do that.

So I ask anyone who can assist me the way how to fix this error because I'm trying this for a day now

PS. I'm installing it on HP Pavillion using USB stick.

**UPDATE**

It just keep stopping and give me error at 60% so I'm not sure really what to do now :(

**UPDATE2**

What I have tried again here is reset the BIOS to the default setting (Incase something changed while we are trying to install Mac)

**UPDATE3**

I've tried to use the ISO for my Windows 7 tbat I'm sure it works because I'm running it on my Parallel and it works fine, so I'm not sure if this is because of the ISO problem or it is actually the partition problem.

Comment: Is this the other topic you're talking about? http://superuser.com/questions/432368/installation-error-0x80070570-while-installing-windows-7

Comment: Yes @OliverSalzburg I did tried that and search many places on the internet (google) no one really fix the problem. I'm not sure if this is because of the corrupt partition or what, but it just happen after I have Mac installed.

Comment: If you want to reformat the HD you could grab a copy of GParted and boot your HP from that. It should find the drive and you should be able to format that to either FAT32 or NTFS. I suggest the latter. Please do make sure that you know which drive you are about to format.

Comment: @Darius It is actually no OS installed on my HD can I still format that?

Comment: Yes, if you're not concerned about loosing data, the answer is yes. Gparted can be found [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Darius I'm going to format my USB to Gparted and will report back ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by a bad "burn" of the DVD. Try burning another DVD and then installing from that. If your DVD burning software has a "Verify" option, use it. Also check the hash of your Windows 8 ISO file.

Comment: Will give that a try.

Comment: @Ali did it help?

Comment: I'm not sure I guess it was that problem, but I did just upgrade to windows 7 first then go to 8

Answer (score 1):

I spent a few hours banging my head against the wall with this error.  I will summarize all the suggestions the 'net in general suggested, which also mirrors what I tried:

1. Change IDE/AHCI/RAID mode in Bios
2. Updated the BIOS to the latest version
3. MemTest and/or replace and/or remove RAM sticks
4. Try a different DVD drive
5. Try a USB install versus slow-burned DVD
6. Try installation to a different hard drive
7. Try Windows 8 and Windows 7

None of that worked, and I always got the same error consistently... until I installed a 32-bit version of Windows instead of the 64-bit versions that I had been trying.  It doesn't seem to matter if it's Home Premium, Ultimate, etc., but for some reason my machine (a few years old Dell) doesn't like the 64-bit install.   I end up losing access to about 750mb of RAM, which is irritating, but this installation nightmare is now over.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a few days trying to solve this and came up with a pretty simple way to do this.
It involves using DiskPart in order to create the bootable media.
Once creating the bootable drive, you simply copy the files over, restart the machine and run it as per normal.
I was using RUFUS which kept giving me the error as well as xboot and think that the software occasionally screws something up.

Run CMD as admin

> **STEP 1**
>
> Type "diskpart" and press enter
>
> - list volume
> - select volume x
>
>   - x being the usb drive number
> - clean
> - create primary partition
> - format fs=ntfs quick
>
>   - ntfs seems to work better than fat32, we use quick as large drives will take some time
> - assign letter=x
>
>   - x being the letter of the drive, used for windows to view the drive

**Step 1 can be done automatically by right clicking USB in My Computer and then clicking format**

> **STEP 2**
>
> If using a ISO, mount it now. If using a DVD then the same
>   instructions follow
>
> Type:
>
> - x:
>
>   - x being the letter of your drive the ISO is mounted too, DVD is       inserted into
> - cd boot
> - bootsect /nt60 x:
>
>   - x being the letter of the USB drive.
>
> You should get a message on CMD saying:
>   **Successfully updated NTFS filesystem bootcode.**
>   **Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes.**

Now Simply open up your windows CD/ISO and copy all the files over to the USB.
Restart your machine, set boot from USB in BIOS and you are good to go.

Hope this helps